# How to literately invoke resource intensive functions

Tags: scala

(1) I have a resource intensive function f whose invocation causes large memory allocations. Because inside f, there will a large collection of objection relations to construct into memory.

(2) However, in my workload, I happen need to invoke function f iteratively such as in a for loop and map function for more than 1K times. In such way, a loop of calling f quickly knock down JVM.

```
for {
    calling f here
}
```

To get the above workload working, I use Thread.sleep right before calling f to introduce interval to delay each iteration of f invocation as below

```
for {
    Thread.sleep (10)
    calling f here
}
```

This elapse time does reduce the total memory usage to get above large workload working.

(3) However, there are known effects: (a) increase the frequency of GC and (b) increase the total response time. Hence, I need to adjust both client and server timeout configuration according. (c) The delay could be linearly grow by which means does not scale up when the iteration is required to grow. (d) If there are concurrent requests to trigger the same above workload at the same time, then other requests will be timeout.

My question: How to literately invoke resource intensive functions:

(A) What is the optimal approach for (2) to process the above one large workload at the same time with the reasonable response time ?
(B) What is the optimal approach for (2) to handle concurrent multiple big workloads at the same time ?

Comment: It’s tricky to say what can be done without knowing details, but if assume that logic in the code is correct and the main problem is that there is no enough resources in JVM, you can try classical solution for such problem - caching and reusing some function’s outputs from previous calls.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `f` doesn't leak resources then then calling it 1000x times in a single thread won't crash jvm because at any given time it allocates resources only for one call.

So I guess you either have a memory leak or you call it from too many different thread. Since `Thread.sleep` has helped I bet on the second. But it is not a reliable solution.

To limit the number of concurrent calls to `f` you can run it on a dedicated `ExecutionContext`.

```
val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10))
..
..
Future {
   call f
}(ec)
```

where `ec` instance is shared between all callers of `f`.

`increase the frequency of GC` problem can't be solved in general: all the garbage you produced has to be collected, no matter how you schedule execution.
But if the program has to be low latency it makes sense to play with GC settings a little bit. If there are many threads that produce lots of short-living garbage you need more space for new garbage and less for long-living one. It used to be `XX:NewSize` setting but perhaps modern garbage collectors work differently.